# SQL query username and password

Tags: sql, perl

I am making a project site for a class but dont understand why im getting this error.
so far i have 
Bareword found where operator expected at user-login.cgi line 14, near "username from usr" also same error and same line "$username AND"
I wasnt able to find any helpful searches. If anyone can help it is greatly appreciated

```
$username = $formdata{'username'};
$password = $formdata{'password'};
$msp = "password";
$msdb = "databasename";
$msusr = "usrname";
$dbh = DBI ->connect("DBI:mysql:$msdb", "$msusr", "$msp");
$check_user = $dbh->selectrow_array(select username from usr WHERE email = $username AND usrpswrd = crypt $password, codetype);
```

this is as far as perl gets when checking the code and gives the error

Answer (score 2):

You should encapsulate your sql with apostrophes. Like this:

```
$check_user = $dbh->selectrow_array("select username from usr WHERE email = $username AND usrpswrd = crypt $password",...
```

(And actually this crypt $password doesn't look good... And you should choose binding the variables instead of creating a big query string with the inputs coming from the user inside. This can be a possible security hole. (Search for sql injection.))

Answer (score 2):

A few issues:

- Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of each and every script.
- You need to enclose your SQL statement in quotes.  I'd suggest using [`q{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/q.html)
- You should [`bind variables`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) instead of including variables in your sql statements.
- Don't forget to [`check for errors`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#DBI%3a%3aerrstr) when connecting to the database and when executing sql queries:
- Because you're using [`selectrow_array`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectrow_array) don't forget to make your left hand side of your assignment a list.

Would therefore suggest these changes (not tested):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

...

my $msp = "password";
my $msdb = "databasename";
my $msusr = "usrname";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$msdb", "$msusr", "$msp")
     or die "DB connect failed: $DBI::errstr";

my $username = $formdata{'username'};
my $password = $formdata{'password'};

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{select username from usr WHERE email=? AND usrpswrd=?});
$sth->execute($username, crypt($password)) or die $dbh->errstr;
my ($check_user) = $sth->fetchrow_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to quote the select

```
"select username from usr WHERE email = '$username' 
    AND usrpswrd = '" . crypt($password)  . "'"
```

You also want to add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the top of your script